# Boundary of an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$

Tags: general-topology

Here is my question: Is the boundary of an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$?

Answer (score 6):

No, it's homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}$, if the immersion is nice enough and in particular if you have in mind the standard embedding of the open ball as the unit ball. Otherwise nasty thing can happen: for example in $\mathbb{R^2}$ you take an open annulus without a ray, it is homeomorphic to a ball but its boundary is not even a topological manifold.

Comment: Actually it can be made homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ if you realize the ball as an open half space for example.

Comment: I see... Here I want to show  the dimension of the boundary is n-1, so one more question, is there a homeomorphism between to $S^{n-1}$  and $\mathbb R^{n-1}$?

Comment: No, homeomorphisms preserve for instance compactness: $S^{n-1}$ is compact and $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is not. They are locally homeomorphic, since $S^{n-1}$ is an $(n-1)$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: What I have for dimension is a recursive definition: a space is of dimension n iff every point has a neighborhood whose boundary is of dimension n-1. I haven't found out how to show $S^{n-1}$ is n-1 dimensional. Can you give some suggestions?

Comment: So, the boundary of an $n-$ball is an $(n-1)-$sphere, any point of an $(n-1)-$sphere has a neighborhood that is an $(n-1)-$ball, whose boundary is an $(n-2)-$sphere... and so on... till you get a $1-$ball, whose boundary is a $0-$sphere (i.e. 2 point), whose dimension is 0. From these using your recursive definition you should get to what you want. (Even it seems that in order to apply your definition you need to give for granted some results that are intuitive, but not so trivial if you haven't seen a definition of manifold).

Comment: Get it. It is in a point set topology course and we haven't talked about manifold yet. But yes, I'll go check out the definition of manifold. Thanks!